# Syncing OneDrive (SkyDrive) with Batch File (via cmd)

Tags: windows, batch-file, onedrive

Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to sync OneDrive with a batch file.  See, I can sync it whenever I go to File Explorer, right click on "OneDrive" on the left, and click "Sync," but I'm wondering if there's command windows has incorporated to have this exact same effect when used with a batch file.  I have no idea what it is and have searched to no avail, so I hope that you can help me!  Whatever it takes, I'm sure it would be an extremely simple script; the problem is finding out what command to use.  Here's an example as a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To shutdown OneDrive from the command line or in a batch file:

```
    %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /shutdown
```

To start OneDrive from the command line:

```
    %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background
```

If the /background switch is omitted then Explorer is opened to the OneDrive folder in your user profile but OneDrive does not start.

If restarting OneDrive from a batch file then add the START command or the batch file won't end:

```
    start %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background
```

Answer (score 2):

Get my [oneDriveSync.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/oneDriveSync.bat) and test it.Be minded that it will work only if machine language is English.THe `Sync` is always the third verb but if it is inactive the third will be `Pause` so I cant create language independent version at the moment.

Comment: I tried it, but when I checked the OneDrive sync icon in the bottom-left corner of the taskbar, it said that it still hadn't been synced since when I last did it myself (without the script you showed me); I have Windows 8.1 Pro, and the machine language is English, so I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: @LaughableJunnyzup - was there any output in the console?

Comment: @LaughableJunnyzup - if you know how to get your access token you can use http requests to do this -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj680723.aspx

Comment: I should mention that I moved the OneDrive folder to the E: Drive.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference.  Yes, the Command Prompt did show some text, but it disappears before I can read it.  I do not know what an access token is, but I'll look into that anyway.

Comment: @LaughableJunnyzup - yes it could make difference.Try to call the bat through opened command prompt.

Comment: @LaughableJunnyzup - I've updated the  oneDriveSync.bat and now its a little bit more robust and now you can pass to the script the location of the oneDrive folder or a shortcut link to it.

Comment: Okay, so what lines of the code that you now have do I have to change to specifically match my computer?  For example, I changed line 47 to link to the OneDrive folder, but still to no avail.  I'm probably missing something, but is there something else that I must change as well?  Also, I tried it from the Command Prompt and I got "OneDrive probably not installed" followed by"Invalid root in the registry key "E:OneDrive".

Comment: @LaughableJunnyzup - try to pass a the location of 'OneDrive' to the script as the first argument.Or a shortcut link.

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple solution:

Change `OneDrive` Settings to NOT Start automatically when Windows starts
Create a BAT file and launch `OneDrive` with `Windows` Task Scheduler during non-peak hours.
Create a `.BAT` file to `Taskkill` `OneDrive.exe` at the end of the Peak-hours:

Windows 10:

Command line to launch OneDrive (and automatically start syncing the folders/files in settings)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe
```

Command line to Taskkill Onedrive.exe

```
Taskkill /IM OneDrive.exe /F
```