# Start OneDrive Under Full Admin Rights

Tags: excel, vba, shell, batch-file, onedrive

## Summary

I necessarily run Excel with Admin privileges and I have UAC set to Never Notify. Excel VBA opens Word. Word has a macro button that restarts OneDrive. The error message is that "OneDrive can't be run using full admin rights." **How can I restart OneDrive without the error massage?**
[image]

Note: There is a sister post at [How to Restart OneDrive via VBA When Running Excel Elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538651/how-to-restart-onedrive-via-vba-when-running-excel-elevated), but that post poses an entirely different question.

## Workflow

### Excel VBA opens Word:

```
Sub m_Test_Finish_WordDoc()
Const strpath = "C:\Users\ssttr\OneDrive\Documents\Investing\Automation\Static Inputs\Restart_OneDrive.docm"

Dim Wd As Object
Dim InstrDoc As Object
Dim f As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

Set InstrDoc = GetObject(strpath)
    
With InstrDoc.Parent
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
End With

End Sub
```

### Word macro restarts OneDrive:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Application.Run "Restart_OneDrive"
End Sub
Sub Restart_OneDrive()
'Restarts OneDrive
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    shell.Run """C:\Users\ssttr\OneDrive\Documents\Investing\Automation\Static Inputs\OneDrive Restart - Copy.bat""" 'bat.zzz
End Sub
```

### Contents of OneDrive Restart - Copy.bat

```
REM Restarts OneDrive from the command line.
REM From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872973/syncing-onedrive-skydrive-with-batch-file-via-cmd.
REM If the /background switch is omitted then Explorer is opened to the OneDrive folder in your user profile but OneDrive does not start.
REM If restarting OneDrive from a batch file then add the START command or the batch file won't end.

            REM start %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background <--  the original '~error-producing' command

            RunWithRestrictedRights %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe -w -v
```

### One Possible Path to a Solution

I downloaded the `RunWithRestrictedRights.exe` standalone executable from https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/RunWithRestrictedRights/ into the C:\Windows\System32 directory and the implementation (shown above) in VBA was replacing the

```
start %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background
```

line in my batch file (which BTW is from [Syncing OneDrive (SkyDrive) with Batch File (via cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872973/syncing-onedrive-skydrive-with-batch-file-via-cmd))
with

```
RunWithRestrictedRights %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe.
```

Note that, as required at the very bottom of https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/RunWithRestrictedRights/, I added the Administrator to the security policy settings for "Replace a process level token" and for "Adjust memory quotas." See below Notes > SecPol.msc §.

The hang-up is when that the batch file, when called in the above process (Important: remember Excel is Run As Admin), runs (i.e. cmd window flashes) but it does not open OneDrive.

**Is my problem, as I suspect, in my batch file, or somewhere else?** If somewhere else, then you may wish to see my sister post (it is the same underlying issue but pursing a very different question) at [How to Restart OneDrive via VBA When Running Excel Elevated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538651/how-to-restart-onedrive-via-vba-when-running-excel-elevated).

## Notes:

### *Things that didn't work for me:*

There was some stuff about UAC being required  relative to an elevated launch of OneDrive, but that's a non-starter for me because if a user needs to attend to a UAC prompt, then my code's purpose of full automation is negated. Also, for my purposes, I have UAC set to Never Notify.

From https://superuser.com/questions/171917/force-a-program-to-run-without-administrator-privileges-or-uac/450503#450503 -- The MS RunAsInvoker Application Compatibility Toolkit shim does not apply bc I have UAC turned off by default.

FWIW, I did try setting UAC to Always Notify but it did not remove the error. I also tried RunAs /trustlevel:0x20000 %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe, and it did not seem to work, which is because per https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/RunWithRestrictedRights/ I have UAC disabled.

### *Origins of the solution I am pursuing:*

From https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/alwaysup/onedrive-hates-admin-rights/ -- "UAC enables an administrator to run OneDrive normally" section -- this is a really informative and provided the final solution

### *SecPol.msc*

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/replace-a-process-level-token -- "This policy setting determines which parent processes can replace the access token (editor's note - describes the security context of a process or thread) that is associated with a child process." That's the lynch pin setting.

I set that per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-rights-assignment and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/how-to-configure-security-policy-settings.

I also had to set Adjust memory quotas for a process per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/adjust-memory-quotas-for-a-process and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/how-to-configure-security-policy-settings.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/how-to-configure-security-policy-settings, "any change to the user rights assignment for an account becomes effective the next time the owner of the account logs on." so I restarted (after I tested and confirmed it did not work without a restart).

[image]

## Update 2022-01-07-18.7

I've moved from a *.bat because I was passing multiple commands, to attempting to directly implement the command by way of:

```
Sub Restart_OneDrive()
     Dim RWRR As Variant
     RWRR = shell("RunWithRestrictedRights.exe ""C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"" -w -p -v", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

but I get Run-time error '53': File not found.

[image: {downlaods runtm53.png}]

The error still occurs if I change to

```
RWRR = shell("C:/Windows/System32/RunWithRestrictedRights.exe ""C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"" -w -p -v", vbNormalFocus)
```

or to

```
Call shell("RunWithRestrictedRights ""C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe""", vbNormalFocus)
```

I have the required security policy set per https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/RunWithRestrictedRights/ :

[image: {downlaods rwrr_secpol.png}]

which states:

> Does RunWithRestrictedRights.exe work on Windows XP and Windows Server
> 2003, where there is no UAC?
>
> Yes, it works well on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. The Windows
> Integrity Level can't be set (that feature is only available in
> Windows Vista and later) but the application is run without admin
> rights as intended.
>
> One note though: If you receive an error stating that "a required
> privilege is not held by the client", please ensure that your account
> has these two rights: Adjust memory quotas for a process; Replace a
> process level token.

If I run directly from a non-elevated command line

```
RunWithRestrictedRights.exe "C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" -w -p -v
```

or

`````
C:/Windows/System32/RunWithRestrictedRights.exe "C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"```` or ````RunWithRestrictedRights "C:\Users\ssttr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" -w -p -v
`````

it works, resulting in:

[image: {rwrrok.png}]

I have tried all these syntax commands inside the shell, with what I think are the appropriate syntax changes, e.g.  as shown the above VBA above, but still get the run time error 53.

FWIW here's the help for RunWithRestrictedRights.exe:

[image: {rwrr help.png}]

which says:

> RunWithRestrictedRights
>
> Synopsis: Runs a given application in a "restricted" mode - at Medium
> (or Low) Integrity and without rights granted by being a member
> of the Administrators group.
>
> Usage:    RunWithRestrictedRights.exe  [-w] [-l] [-p]
> [-v]
> [-d ]
>
> Options:
>  The full path to the application to be started. Please be
> sure to enclose the path in quotes if it contains at least
> one space.
> -w            Instead of returning immediately after launching the
> application, wait until the application ends. Optional.
> -l            Instead of running the application with Medium Integrity,
> start it with Low Integrity. Optional.
> -p            Also strip away rights granted from being a member of the
> "Power Users" group. Optional.
> -d       Also deny rights to the given SID.
> -v            Produce verbose output. Optional.
>
> Exit code:        The non-zero process identifier (PID) if the
> application
> was successfully started.
> -1 if there was an error starting the application.
>
> Version:          3.0.1.16 (Feb 18 2020)
>
> Example:          > RunWithRestrictedRights.exe "C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe"
> - Starts MyApp.exe with retricted rights.
>
> This free utility is Copyright 2020, Core Technologies Consulting,
> LLC. Find out about this and our other products at our web site:
> https://www.CoreTechnologies.com/

Comment: Quick thought after not having read the whole post: Why are you incorporating a batch file rather than just running `RunWithRedtrictedRights.exe` directly?

Comment: I used a *.bat because I was passing multiple commands, but since you pointed it out, I've been trying to run directly but get Run-time error '53': File not found. I've appended more detail to the original post under the heading Update 2022-01-07-18.7.